# Capybara Rspec test fails possibly do to AJAX - testing contenteditables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara, contenteditable

I am trying to test whether or not a contenteditable textarea works in my code, but I am getting an error that I can't seem to fix.  The issue is that the params being sent to the controller are not what I expect from the AJAX. Here is my code:

**rspec**

```
describe 'editing contenteditables', js: true do
  before do
    page.find('#artistdescription').set('Pizza')
    page.find('#similarArtists').click #in order to blur out of contenteditable
  end

  it {should have_content('Pizza')}
end
```

**view**

```
<% if @is_current_artist %>
  <% description_text = (@artist.description.blank? && @is_current_artist) ? "test" : @artist.description %>
  <textarea contenteditable='true' id='artistdescription'>
    <%= description_text %>
  </textarea>
<% else %>
  ...
```

**AJAX**

```
 $(document).on('blur', '#artistdescription', ->
  $.ajax(
    url: "/artists/" + $('#idnumber').html()
    type: "PATCH"
    datatype: "JSON"
    data: {
      artist: {
        description: $('#artistdescription').val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")
      }
      session_code: getCookie('session_code');
    } 
  )
)
```

**controller**

```
def update
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
    p 'Hello from update'
    return if !active_session && !is_current_artist
    p 'Logged in!'
    pp artist_params
    @artist.update_attributes(artist_params) #error here

  def artist_params
    #Add more contenteditable stuff here
    p '=====================TASTY TACOS!'
    pp params
    params.require(:artist).permit(:artist_name, :route_name, :password, :email, :background_image, :description, :hometown, :genre) #error here
  end
```

**and here is my error message**

```
"Hello from update"
"Logged in!"
"=====================TASTY TACOS!"
{"action"=>"update", "controller"=>"artists", "id"=>"1"}
F

Failures:

  1) Current Artist editing contenteditables should text "Pizza"
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: artist
     # ./app/controllers/artists_controller.rb:151:in `artist_params'
     # ./app/controllers/artists_controller.rb:48:in `update'

Finished in 15.41 seconds (files took 16.02 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/editting_artist_spec.rb:32 # Current Artist editting contenteditables should text "Pizza"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What if you use `page.find('#similarArtists').blur` instead? I don't know if there is a significant difference between `.blur` and `.click`, but this has to be confirmed / refuted

Comment: It didn't work. I tried both `page.find('#similarArtists').blur` and `page.find('#artistdescription').blur` and neither works:
`Failure/Error: page.find('#artistdescription').blur
NoMethodError: undefined method 'blur' for #<Capybara::Node::Element:0xbaa60814>`

Comment: Hey I just noticed that you set the event listener on `$(document).on('blur', '#artistdescription', handler)` but your simulated click action is on `page.find('#similarArtists').click`. Maybe it should be `page.find('#artistdescription').click`?

Comment: It didn't work.  Even though I got a different failure, the console messages that I placed in the controller didn't appear in the rspec, which means that the AJAX didn't run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with QtWebkit itself, as Finch mentioned above:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/553

There's a workaround, sending a POST request and manually redirecting to the `update` controller method (detailed here):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17870287/472768

Comment: It worked, the params are showing the description!  `"Hello from update"
"Logged in!"
"=====================TASTY TACOS!"
{"action"=>"update",
 "artist"=>{"description"=>"Pizza"},
 "session_code"=>"jeBPERlH2y2utkh28CjChw",
 "controller"=>"artists",
 "id"=>"1"}
{"description"=>"Pizza"}
"=====================TASTY TACOS!"
{"action"=>"update",
 "artist"=>{"description"=>"Pizza"},
 "session_code"=>"jeBPERlH2y2utkh28CjChw",
 "controller"=>"artists",
 "id"=>"1"}`

Answer (score 1):

A good way to fix this is to force the page to wait until all of the outstanding ajax requests have finished before allowing the tests to continue. The gist is that you have to log each time a request is made and each time a request finishes.

In a js file `called test.js`

```
//= require jquery

var requestsFinished = false;

$(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    requestsFinished = true;
  });
});
```

In your `.erb` templates

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'test' if Rails.env.test? %>
```

In the `spec_helper.rb`

```
config.include(RequestHelper, :type => :feature)
```

In a file called `request_helper.rb`

```
module RequestHelper
  def self.included(base)
    base.metadata[:js] = true

    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
  end

  class InstanceMethods
    def wait_for_ajax
      page.wait_until {
        page.execute_script(<<-JS)
          if(!requestsFinished) {
            throw "Requests not finished";
          }
        JS
      }
    end
```

And finally in you request tests

```
page.execute_script(<<-JS)
  $(document).trigger('blur');
JS

wait_for_ajax

page.should have_content('Success')
```

Comment: I don't currently have submit buttons. The functionality is intended to save on blur.

Comment: trigger blur directly on the element that you have set the event handler on. (in your cases document) `$(document).trigger('blur');`

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the issue:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/553

The problem is within the testing system itself. Thank you for your help.  If you guys have an answer though, please post it.